# Linux Link Speed Advertise

Tags: linux-networking, ethtool

As far as I know, the following command would set the speed and duplex advertised by auto-negotiation.

```
ethtool -s eth0 advertise 0x020
```

where `0x020` indicates `1000baseT Full` according to the following guide:

```
advertise N
    Sets the speed and duplex advertised by autonegotiation.  The 
    argument is a hexadecimal value using one or a combination of
    the following values:
      0x001       10baseT Half
      0x002       10baseT Full
      0x004       100baseT Half
      0x008       100baseT Full
      0x010       1000baseT Half       (not supported by IEEE standards)
      0x020       1000baseT Full
```

The command I applied, advertises `1000baseT Full` only. I wonder to know how I set the server to advertise multiple link modes like `1000baseT Full 100baseT Full 100baseT Half` all at once.

I have tried applying the same command for desired link modes one by one, but every time the new link mode replaces the current mode and not added to it.

I have also mentioned the link modes hexacodes consecutively like the following but it returns an error.

```
ethtool -s eth0 advertise 0x020 0x008 0x004
    ethtool: bad command line argument(s)
    For more information run ethtool -h
```

When all are advertised, they are displayed in the `ethtool` output like this:

```
ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full 
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                                1000baseT/Half 1000baseT/Full
```

Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the numbers up. Observe that:

- `0x001` is `0b000000000001`,
- `0x002` is `0b000000000010`,
- `0x004` is `0b000000000100`,

and so on, each of them represents one bit (flag) in some register, which stores whichever modes are enabled. You need to just enable all wanted bits.

In your case, `1000baseT Full`, `100baseT Full` and `100baseT Half` would be `0x020 + 0x008 + 0x004 = 0x02c`:

```
ethtool -s eth0 advertise 0x02c
```

Comment: It absolutely works. Thank you so much for your help.